# Ignore rails form validations (Reject a form)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an `Approve` and a `Reject` button in rails form.
If someone clicks on `Reject` I do not want to go through all the form validations, say for instance text fields that are marked as required, while rejecting the form, I don't care if they are filled.
How can I handle this?

Rails version: 5.0.1

```
 <input type="submit" name="model_action" value="Approve" </input>
    <input type="submit" name="model_action" value="Reject"></input>
```

Comment: How do you validate input fields ? on form (view) or in model ?

Comment: form view I use form attributes like required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html has a form attribute called `formnovalidate`
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formnovalidate.asp

So for my code, to the reject button I added `formnovalidate`

So when `Reject` is clicked, form validations are not taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

Simply,You can add javascript for handle `reject` button clicked.
Try with JS on click event.